# Implementing xml rpc server on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-rpc

I'm developing an app to exchange data between an Android phone and a pc. I've chosen xml-rpc as a way to communicate, and as a library i downloaded android-xmlrpc (https://code.google.com/p/android-xmlrpc/).
When I call remote procedures from my phone, I use the XMLRPCClient and it works almost fine.
But then I have to synchronize data from my server to the application, so I need to listen on a given port and wait for a xmlrpc request.
I tried the following code:

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
   try {  ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(8888);
          XMLRPCServer server = new XMLRPCServer();
          while (true) {
             Socket client = socket.accept();
             MethodCall call = server.readMethodCall(client);
             String name = call.getMethodName();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Server: Error", e); }
        return null;
    }
```

But it seems it never receives any procedure call. I mean, to debug it I'm trying to use my XMLRPCClient as follow:

```
XMLRPCClient client = new XMLRPCClient("http://127.0.0.1:8888/");
Object o = client.call("add",1,3);
Log.v(LOG_TAG, o.toString());
```

And I always get no response. It's stuck on readMethodCall and never reads that the method I requested is "add"... It's strange it gets stuck there. Can't figure the reason why it is stucked here. Do you have any idea ?